# Document Store database design in mongoDB to store multiple xml feeds

Tags: mongodb

I have a task to model the Document Store database in mongoDB.
Please help me to design DB xml model for storing multiple types of XML feeds  such as rss ,atom .
The data should be stored with versioning like git (changes overtime should be traced )
and also we should provide scailable advanced Data Model .

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic for StackOverflow. Lots of ways to model data. This is very broad and opinion-soliciting. And what, exactly, does *scalable advanced data model* even mean?

Comment: It means that the data is going to become big data and should be stored correctly

Comment: Right - so what does "big data" mean? Terabytes? Petabytes? What does "stored correctly" mean? There's no definition of storing something "correctly" - it's all about your app and its write and read patterns (and which of those you need to optimize for). You can have referenced documents, embedded documents (and a combination of the two), shards, etc.

Comment: I think it terabytes or Petabytes doesn't change the structure.I need to create such a Model that can be the best solution for feeds .I mean for example exchange feed and weather forecast should be stored in different xml files but I don't know if it is right to do some normalization as the theoretically the structure shouldn't change for these kind of things.

Comment: "also **we** should provide scailable advanced Data Model " Are you asking the community to do your freaking _job_?

Comment: Not at all, I need some approach. Designing the database for feeds is not complex for relational databases but modeling on mongoDb for me something new .I have surfed and researched about that but not found exact right and correct variant.
I need someone that should point for example you have to create 2  objects with these properties and he can explain his solution.